# What is the difference between *per* and *pere de*?

Tags: word-meaning

This question came up on another site and I thought it was a good one.

What is the difference between *per* and *pere de*? Both can be translated as "by means of". Can someone list some examples of these in use that would illustrate the difference?

Answer (score 7):

Basically *per* refers to a direct means *(uze de)*, while *pere de* refers to an indirect means *(parte dank' al, pro haveblo de)*. The reason, I think, is that *pere* does not come directly from *per* but is the adverbial form of *pera* *(= ne efikanta per si mem).*

- *Mi lernis ĝin per reta kurso.* I learnt it with an online course.
- *Mi lernis ĝin pere de reta kurso.* I learnt it with the help of [because I had access to] an online course.

A good example would be *vojaĝi pere de Esperanto* ("travel by means of/with the help of Esperanto"), which avoids implying that learning Esperanto gives you teleportation powers, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The answer I posted in the other site was:

*Oni parolas per la buŝo kaj pere de interpretisto.*