# <prepozicio>e de io

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

Jen kelke da frazoj sufiĉe simplaj.

> Li venas al la butiko.
> La monado estis ĵetita el la fenestro kaj falis sur la grundon.
> La unua umo staras post la dua umo.
> Antaŭ ri ruliĝas monado tre granda.

Mi fojfoje vidas aldonadon de «de» post prepozicio adverbigita. Jen ekzemplo iomete "meta".

> Mi fojfoje vidas aldonadon de «de» post**e de** prepozicio adverbigita.

Kiam estas tio, ke "<prepozicio>e de"...

1. ...estus ĝusta?
2. ...havus la malsaman signifon kiel nur "<prepozicio>" mem?

Jen la frazoj, denove, sed umigite.

> Li venas ale de la butiko.
> La monado estis ĵetita ele de la fenestro kaj falis suren de la grundo.
> La unua umo staras poste de la dua umo.
> Antaŭe de ri ruliĝas monado tre granda.

Ĝis nun, mi scias nur tion, ke "per" ≠ "pere de", sed mi ne certas pri aliaj. Tamen mi jam havas senton sufiĉe grandan, ke iuj el tiuj iel estas malĝustaj, precipe "ale de", "ele de", kaj probable la pli absurda "dee de". Kie ajn mi eble vidis tiajn formojn, mi vidis nur "poste de" kaj "antaŭe de", mi pensas, do mi nun scivolas pri la aliaj formoj, se tiuj eĉ estas/ekzistas.

Due, se almenaŭ iuj estas ĝustaj, mi ankaŭ scivolas tion, kiel funkcius la pseŭdolokativo "-en", tiuokaze.

> La ento fluis de unu spaco en alian ebenon.
> La ento fluis de unu spaco enen de alia ebeno.

Ĉu ĝuste? Ĉu tro strange? Ĉu tro abstrakte? Ĉu tute absurde?

Englishly speaking, even if some of these are indeed grammatically incorrect, I do have a feeling that even something like "ale de" or "ene de" could make sense, if one really thinks about it. English is not the best language to express this, nor is it my first language, but those two, for example, could be expressed roughly as "towardsly from" and "in[ternally] from/of", respectively, and similarly for the rest.

Atentu tion, ke mi demandas sole pri ĝusteco gramatika, kaj ne pri bonparolado. Lingvludado estas sufiĉe amuza, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via demando rilatas tion, [kion PMEG nomas `rolvortaĵoj`](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/rolvortajhoj.html):

> Ekzistas tre multaj esprimoj, kiuj konsistas el E-vorto + de:
>
> ```
> Meze de = “en la mezo de”: Meze de la arbaro apud grupo de laboristoj staris Valdemaro Doe kun siaj tri filinoj.FA4.79 = En la
> ```
>
> mezo de la arbaro... Similaj estas komence de (= “en la komenco de”),
> fine de (= “en la fino de”), ene de (= “en la eno de” = “en”), interne
> de (= “en la interno de”) kaj ekstere de (= “ekster”).

Ili ekzistas ankaŭ kun `al`, kaj `kun`. La menciita paĝo de PMEG listigas kelkajn tiajn.

Comment: Jes, ekzistas multaj tiaj esprimoj, sed ekz. "mezo", "komenco", "fino" kaj "interno" ne estas prepozicioj.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas prave. Tiuj PMEG-aj rolvortaĵoj ankaŭ fareblas el aliaj elementoj, ne nur el prepozicioj.

Answer (score 1):

Estas ĝenerale konata, ke oni komprenu la prepoziciojn de Esperanto pli laŭlitere ol en aliaj lingvoj por atingi unusencecon. Ĉi tial en [alia diskuto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/what-is-the-difference-between-per-and-pere-de) oni argumentis, ke "per" montras rektan rimedon kaj "pere de" havas alian sencon, sencon de "kun helpo de". Oni havis ekzemplon

- Oni parolas per la buŝo kaj pere de interpretisto.

Laŭ mi la esenca demando estas, ĉu tiaj adverbigitaj prepozicioj plus de -esprimoj servas al iu celo, ĉu ili esprimas ion, kion oni ne povas esprimi alimaniere, eble pli klare. En la okazo de "pere de" tiu pli klara esprimo estas "kun helpo de".

Kion signifas "ale de", "ele de" ktp., kion oni ne povas esprimi alimaniere? Mi ne eĉ komprenas, kion ili signifas.

Kiam temas pri "poste de", mi trovis [ekzemplon](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domo_Batll%C3%B3) (en Vikipedio), en kiu la uzo estas komprenebla minimume al mi.

> [tie]… estis vendejo, unue de entrepreno de fotografio Lumière, poste de la kinproduktorejo Pathé Frères kaj poste de la Galerio Syra.

Ĉi tie "poste de" servas ordigi la eventojn, t.e. la kinproduktorejo situis tie post la fotografio kaj post la kinproduktorejo situis la galerio.

Fine notu, ke mi opinias, ke la prepozicio "de" jam havas tro multajn signifojn (13 laŭ [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#de_kd)), do estas bona ideo eviti krei pliajn.

Comment: En la ekzemplo de Vikipedio, la frazo verŝajne signifas "Unue [tie] estis vendejo de entrepreno de fotografio Lumière, **poste** [tie estis vendejo] **de** la kinproduktorejo Pathé Frères kaj **poste** [tio tie estis vendejo] **de** la Galerio Syra." Do la _poste_-oj kaj la la _de_-oj staras unu post la alia, sed havas alian signifon ol "poste de" en aliaj frazoj.

Comment: Vi pravas, kaj via observo klare montras, do al kiu celo servas esprimoj, kiujn oni ne komprenas sammaniere.